# How can I replicate this UI behaviour

Tags: android, kotlin, responsive-design

How can I replicate this behaviour in an Android app, is only for learning purposes. I do know that in the bottom half they are using a recyclerview, but in the upper part where they are displaying the "You have 4.983 to spend" part I dont know how to add it, how do they split the screen to have them both? This is what I want to replicate[image: kotlin]

Comment: use MotionLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the code or implementation which you have tried before asking the question, which will be helpful for others to answer your question.

This can be implemented easily within the same xml layout file.
Or
Can also be done with multiple fragments split in one activity or fragment.

Think each TextView ImageView or any Widget as to be placed properly into one layout. Just for an example for you to set i have created this which took me 5 mins to build similar layout design like one you have posted, the final result is not same, because details are to be customized.

So import this xml into your file and see how it looks. Also learn using ConstraintLayout.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/you_have_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="You have"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$ 4,983"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/you_have_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/you_have_text" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/first_card"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/second_card"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amount_text">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Funds"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/second_card"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/third_card"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/first_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amount_text">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Transfer"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/third_card"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/second_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/first_card">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Pay Bill"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/list_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_card">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_card"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_list" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="32dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    tools:text="McDonalds" />
```